# The pronunciation of the word "window"

Tags: phonology

As you know when the letter w placed at the end of a word, it is pronounced like **'oo'**  in the words book and could as seen on the chart below.It can be shown as **/w/** or  **/ʊ/** too in dictionaries.

I am not sure but I think it still can be pronounced like **'oo'**  in the word book even though the letter w placed as the first letter of a word.For example : Watch like **ooatch** or **ʊatch**.What do you think?

But when it comes to the word **window**, can we say the **first** letter w is pronounced like   **'oo'**  like **ooindoo** or **ʊindoʊ**

OR

the **first** letter **w** is pronounced  like **/v/** in the word volcano as seen in the chart? /v/indoo  or /v/indoʊ

[image]

Comment: In North American and much of British English, "w" is pronounced nothing like the "v" in "volcano." That's more an Indian English thing. The "oo" is closer, but only because following it with "i" forces most of us to make the true "w" sound.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Hi James thank you for your answer.I should say I know    the letter w is pronounced like 'oo' normally. But can we say that the word window is kinda exception.Actually I couldn't understand your answer especially the last sentence.What is the true "w" sound.

Comment: It's a pure consonant and can't be expresses using only vowels. How is "window" different from "work," "ward," "word," or "widow?" I see nothing exceptional about it.

Comment: /w/ is not pronounced the same as the ‘oo’ sound, /u/, nor as the short ‘u’ sound, /ʊ/. They are three different sounds, three different phonemes. There is no exception in _window_. The first sound is the phoneme /w/ (a consonant), and the last sound is the phoneme /oʊ/. Note that the ‘o’ sound is _one_ phoneme. There is no /w/ at the end of _window_, only in writing.

Answer (score 3):

American teenager here. Here is a recording of my pronunciation of it: http://vocaroo.com/i/s1QN5mkcBC7f

Comment: Likewise age 53, Central PA.

Answer (score 2):

The first sound of "window" is very close to the "oo" sound in "book", except in "window" it's a glide, while "oo" in "book" is a vowel.  A glide, unlike a vowel, does not have a steady state -- a time during which the quality does not change appreciably.  A glide does not count for a syllable -- for instance, both "win" and "in" have just one syllable, even though "win" begins with a glide which is absent from "in".